# heroku bundler: failed to load command: rackup

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra

I'm trying to deploy to heroku a modular sinatra app that works fine locally. This is in the heroku logs:

```
2020-12-28T21:05:15.907560+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rackup config.ru -p 58645`
2020-12-28T21:05:18.738254+00:00 app[web.1]: bundler: failed to load command: rackup (/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/bin/rackup)
2020-12-28T21:05:18.738283+00:00 app[web.1]: Gem::Exception: can't find executable rackup for gem rack. rack is not currently included in the bundle, perhaps you meant to add it to your Gemfile?
```

The command `bundle exec rackup config.ru -p 58645` runs fine locally.

This is my config.ru

```
require_relative './config/environment.rb'
use EntreeController
use UserController
run ApplicationController
```

and environment.rb

```
APP_ENV = ENV["RACK_ENV"] || "development"
ENV['SINATRA_ENV'] ||= "development"

require 'require_all'
require 'bundler/setup'
Bundler.require(:default, ENV['SINATRA_ENV'])

require_all 'app'
require_all 'app/models'
require_all 'app/helpers'
```

And the Procfile:

```
web: bundle exec rackup config.ru -p $PORT
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll post my solution, if ever someone bumps into the same problem. I had followed the indication on the `Rakefile` here : https://github.com/sinatra-activerecord/sinatra-activerecord.

One solution was to entirely deleted the Rakefile when deploying to Heroku. The other solution is to put only this in the Rakefile :

```
require "sinatra/activerecord"
require "sinatra/activerecord/rake"
require "./app" # or whereever your app is
```

Answer (score 0):

Switching to Bundler 2.1.4 solved the problem in my case.

For the longer run one will have to install bundler 2.1.4 and use it, but for the sake of test I just manually edited that line in `Gemfile.lock`:

```
BUNDLED WITH
   2.1.4
```

I was using Ruby 2.7.2 and Bundler 2.2.8 — Heroku buildpack provided Bundler 2.1.4.

Funny that Heroku’s [Bundler bugs list](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-version#known-upgrade-issues) had nothing about 2.2.8.